# puma ignoring my configuration file

Tags: puma

I'm trying to start puma with 2 workers, but when it starts the logs say:

```
Puma 2.11.3 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: production
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
```

config/puma.rb:

```
workers Integer(ENV['PUMA_WORKERS'] || 2)
threads Integer(ENV['PUMA_MIN_THREADS']  || 1), Integer(ENV['PUMA_MAX_THREADS'] || 6)
```

Any idea why puma is launched with 0 min thread rather than 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is one of those [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=RTFM) questions. The [puma documentation](https://github.com/puma/puma#configuration-file) states:

> *when using the* RACK_ENV environment variable, the default file location will be config/puma/environment_name.rb.

so the fix is to relocate `config/puma.rb` into `config/puma/production.rb`